# "cannot list resources" error from WooCommerce REST API

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I am very new to WordPres` and using the WooCommerce plugin for the first time and want to use the WooCommerce REST API in my Android app.

I have enabled the REST API and created a Consumer Key as well as a Consumer secret.

Now, when am using this url `http://www.my-domain.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/` in my browser to check if the API is working or not, I get this error:

> {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot
>   list resources.","data":{"status":401}}

SSL is not installed on my server. How can I fix this? Do I need to use the PHP Client Library?

Answer (score 29):

**Authentication Methods**

For the newer APIs (not the "legacy" APIs):

- For secure connections (HTTPS), you need to use "Basic Authentication".
- For non-secure connections (HTTP), you need to use "oAuth1 Authentication".

If you use the wrong authentication with the wrong connection, you'll get the 401 response message.

This is covered in the WooCommerce API documentation:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-https

**API login username and password**
*(also "Consumer key is missing" error)*

Normally you would pass the CK and CS in as header fields, but depending on how the server is configured, you may find that it will not parse the header fields correctly, so you may get success if you include the CK and CS in the URL as parameters:

[https://website.tld/wp-json/wc/v1/products?consumer_key=[key]&consumer_secret=[secret]](https://website.tld/wp-json/wc/v1/products?consumer_key=%5Bkey%5D&consumer_secret=%5Bsecret%5D)

**Apache authorization variable**

You may need to fill the authorization variable in Apacheif you use FCGId. In your .htaccess or sites sections, add this :

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

(https://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/12825/rest-authentication-does-not-work-under-default-cgi-configurations-solution-within/p1)

Comment: This is true for v3 as well. If you're running on localhost for example, simply use OAuth 1.0, providing only the consumer key and consumer secret and leaving all other properties blank

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add this to my `.htaccess` file.

Needed for WooCommerce API:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Comment: This answer saved me. To test `HTTP`, I have fixed from `Basic Auth` to `oAuth 1.0`. But it doesn't work yet. After adding ultimately that line at `.htaccess` file, it's worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 401 response from the server. This response indicates the you are not authorized for that REST endpoint. In order to use the woocommerce api you need to include your authorization in the request.

There are examples and documentation here:
http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication

The woocommerce examples don't include java examples. (I assume that is what you are using for your android app). However there is a 3rd party java library for woocommerce. It can be found here:
https://github.com/icoderman/wc-api-java

I have not personally used that library, but it should contain all the functions you will need to authorize and correctly request data from the woocommerce api.

Comment: Okay! but how can I include authorization in the request?

Comment: If you go to the link I posted there are simple examples you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the 'Authorization' tab on Postman. Select OAuth 1.0 as the 'Type'. Fill up the 'Consumer Key' & 'Consumer Secret' that's it.

In my case, I left the 'Access Token' and 'Token Secret' fields blank, and it worked.

Screenshots
https://prnt.sc/TxugsENfE96n
https://prnt.sc/ESA6UfEqD1G5

Answer (score 0):

Go to /wp-admin
step-1: In Woocommerce tab Go to Setting
step-2: In setting Click on advanced
: You can find REST Api option below Advanced
click on that and generate api key.
now send that key and Secret in header uri
URL look like:
***https://Yoursite.local/wp-json/wc/v3/products?
consumer_key=YourKey&consumer_secret=YourSecret***
Now You can Easily access.