# Why is woocommerce rest api not working? I am trying to access product details as json through woocommerce rest api

Tags: wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to access product details as json through woocommerce rest api. Rest api is enabled in backend and cusumer key and secret is also generated some how it's not working please suggest me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose the correct authorization type which is OAuth 1.0 and then you input your consumer key and secret in the empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can not authenticate just by passing the CK and CS in the payload.

You need to use the appropriate authentication method for the call to the end point:

- HTTPS - Basic authentication
- HTTP - oAuth 1

As Basic authentication is easier, and HTTPS is now the norm, I'd suggest that route.  See my answer [here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593704/cannot-list-resources-error-from-woocommerce-rest-api/51210642#51210642).