# Woocommerce REST API Error: Sorry, you cannot list resources

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce, http-status-code-401

When i trying to access the orders through Woocommerce  API it getting "Fatal error: Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: Error: Sorry, you cannot list resources." and Analysis reports also not working.

[woocommerce  API Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfENp.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["cannot list resources" error from WooCommerce REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593704/cannot-list-resources-error-from-woocommerce-rest-api)

Comment: No.
This is my error on Site health.
The REST API encountered an unexpected result.
The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.
The REST API call gave the following unexpected result: (404) {"description":"","hierarchical":false,"name":"Posts","slug":"post","taxonomies":["category","post_tag"],"rest_base":"posts","_links":{"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/shivangiclothing.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types"}],.....